# how can i remove the mystery .azdownload prefixed files

Tags: azure, azcopy

I have a powershell script, in it calls azcopy to list, download then delete the files from azure blob, all runs good except there a few .azDownload+guid prefixed files show up.. now what i do with those files, it seeems some of them are legitimate files, just the prefix is the issue, how can i fix it?

Comment: Can you please provide the script you tried and what are the files missing from the result?

Answer (score 0):

found it, it appears azdownload was an interim file produced by azcopy, simply put in a delay script before downstream able to pick up solve the issue.. would it be better if azcopy can write the temp/interim file somewhere else to avoid confusion!